# ExpressionEngine 2 all sub pages return "File not found"

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, expressionengine

I am working on an ExpressionEngine 2 site and I'm having problems, I believe, with my rewrite rules. I'm able to access the main site without any issues, but the moment I try to access any sub-pages I'm met with a plain white screen and the simple phrase "File not found." (The page source is also just this text.)

What's weird is it will work on my friends' computers which leads me to believe it's a problem with my server configuration. I'm running a Vagrant box built from Puphpet using Ubuntu 14.04.5, and Apache2. Below are my .htaccess rewrite rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now, if I change the last line to `RewriteRule ^.(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` then everything works normally (adding the ? after .php). However, as I said it works perfectly well on my friends' computers and I'd like to fix this issue at the root as it's symptomatic of all EE2 sites I work on.

What do I need to look into to try fixing this? I already researched if $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] works and it does. I'm at a loss.

Thank you for any help or light you can shed on the matter.

P.S.
I saw in the ExpressionEngine 2 docs that adding the ? is a way around when a host requires forcing query strings. How do I disable that?